# llvm-py questions

Tags: python, llvm

1) Is it possible to use llvm-py on Windows without Visual Studio 2008? Maybe I can compile files on another computer and use on my?

2) Is llvm-py mature enough in your opinion? If not, what are the problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, llvm-py is unmaintained. The project would require some kind of compiler, although you should be able to use the free VS express edition I would imagine.

On the other hand, the LLVM C bindings are maintained, so it is always possible to use the Python ctypes module to wrap the LLVM C API, without having to compile anything (assuming you already have a copy of LLVM compiled for your platform).